# How to set specific static option with C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set gameobject static check with the script and actually i have achieve it through this

```
gameObject.isStatic = true;
```

but the problem is, it is setting static for all:
[image]

I only want to set static for Occluder Static and Occludee Static.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var flags = StaticEditorFlags.OccluderStatic | StaticEditorFlags.OccludeeStatic;
GameObjectUtility.SetStaticEditorFlags(gameObject,flags);
```

Comment: While this is true, you can't set it during tun-time in a build. This is for Editor use only.